# Flash AS3 loop 3 times and stop on specific frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've designed a simple web banner that I'd like to loop 3 times.

In my timeline, I've created a blank layer for my ActionScript. The first frame contains the following ActionScript:

```
var loops:int;
```

The final frame contains the following ActionScript:

```
loops = loops + 1;
if (loops == 3) {
    stop();
}
```

This loops the animation 3 times. On the final loop, I'd like the animation to stop on a certain frame. This is because the animation usually fades out to loop again. Is this possible?

Comment: That seems correct. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: What's the problem? Insert the second code to the certain frame.

Comment: This is my fault. I was putting the second code at the end instead of the frame where I wanted the animation to stop. I'm happy to award the answer to either of you or I'll delete the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the second code to the certain frame.

Comment: Easy money. Cheers buddy!